# How to read only n rows of large CSV file on HDFS using spark-csv package?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hdfs, apache-spark-sql, spark-csv

I have a big distributed file on HDFS and each time I use sqlContext with spark-csv package, it first loads the entire file which takes quite some time.

```
df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true', inferschema='true').load("file_path")
```

now as I just want to do some quick check at times, all I need is few/ any n rows of the entire file.

```
df_n = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true', inferschema='true').load("file_path").take(n)
df_n = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true', inferschema='true').load("file_path").head(n)
```

but all these run after the file load is done. Can't I just restrict the number of rows while reading the file itself ? I am referring to n_rows equivalent of pandas in spark-csv, like:

```
pd_df = pandas.read_csv("file_path", nrows=20)
```

Or it might be the case that spark does not actually load the file, the first step, but in this case, why is my file load step taking too much time then?

I want

```
df.count()
```

to give me only `n` and not all rows, is it possible ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My understanding is that reading just a few lines is not supported by spark-csv module directly, and as a **workaround** you could just read the file as a text file, take as many lines as you want and save it to some temporary location. With the lines saved, you could use spark-csv to read the lines, including `inferSchema` option (that you may want to use given you are in exploration mode).

```
val numberOfLines = ...
spark.
  read.
  text("myfile.csv").
  limit(numberOfLines).
  write.
  text(s"myfile-$numberOfLines.csv")
val justFewLines = spark.
  read.
  option("inferSchema", true). // <-- you are in exploration mode, aren't you?
  csv(s"myfile-$numberOfLines.csv")
```

Comment: +1 although wouldn't .read() be read by multiple executors so the order of .limit() is not guranteed? In other words, yes you get `numberOfLines` lines but those aren't necessary first lines in the original "myfile.csv", isn't it?

Comment: I tried this but text().limit(2) seems to be reading the whole file first, which in my case is several GBs.

Comment: @Vaibhav That seems your file is not split due to a large split size on HDFS and simply fits into one single split (?) Just guessing. You should ask a separate question and provide more information, e.g. query plan and HDFS configuration.

Comment: @Tagar My understanding is that the order is guaranteed. Upon uploading a CSV file onto HDFS, the splits will be in order and that's what Spark knows about the file.

Comment: I notice the csv reader has the option `samplingRatio – defines fraction of rows used for schema inferring. If None is set, it uses the default value, 1.0.` Perhaps that is a performant way to infer the schema whilst in exploration, and help you to explicitly specify schema for performance & repeatability in production.

Answer (score 23):

You can use `limit(n)`.

```
sqlContext.format('com.databricks.spark.csv') \
          .options(header='true', inferschema='true').load("file_path").limit(20)
```

This will just load 20 rows.

Comment: Would that preclude `inferSchema`, i.e. what if I used `inferSchema` enabled?

Comment: If you inferSchema, all the data will be scanned anyway. Scanned and not loaded.

Comment: How is scanning different from loading?

Comment: Scanning as a passing over the data and loaded as in putting the data in memory... I'm not sure I don't get what you don't get about that @JacekLaskowski :-/

Comment: "Scanning as a passing over the data" == "loaded as in putting the data in memory" are the same things on Spark executors.

Comment: No man it's not. :) and by exploration, the OP is referring to the data exploration process in data analysis...

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't agree with you on this one @JacekLaskowski

Comment: @eliasah provided solution loads file first and then limit it. How is this going to help if I am having a petabyte file ? this will anyway load all the rows and then show limited records n.

Comment: The solution is to read a part of file as it will be in a distributed environment.         
sqlContext.format('com.databricks.spark.csv') \
          .options(header='true', inferschema='true').load("file_path/part-00000* ")

Answer (score 4):

Not inferring schema and using `limit(n)` worked for me, in all aspects.

```
f_schema = StructType([
StructField("col1",LongType(),True),
StructField("col2",IntegerType(),True),
StructField("col3",DoubleType(),True)
...
])

df_n = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true').schema(f_schema).load(data_path).limit(10)
```

**Note:** If we use `inferschema='true'`, its again the same time, and maybe hence the same old thing.

But if we dun have idea of the schema, Jacek Laskowski solutions works well too. :)

Comment: It's always going to be better to explicitly provide the schema, if you have it. You could use `inferSchema`  the first time you read it and then save & use the `df.schema` for later, but if the files are so huge that doing it even once is too much, then the workaround suggested is right. The correct answer is a combination of this and https://stackoverflow.com/a/44277219/1335793

Answer (score 4):

The solution given by Jacek Laskowski works well. Presenting an in-memory variation below.

I recently ran into this problem. I was using databricks and had a huge csv directory (200 files of 200MB each)

I originally had

```scala
val df = spark.read.format("csv")
.option("header", true)
.option("sep", ",")
.option("inferSchema", true)
.load("dbfs:/huge/csv/files/in/this/directory/")

display(df)
```

which took a lot of time (10+ minutes), but then I change it to below and it ran instantly (2 seconds)

```scala
val lines = spark.read.text("dbfs:/huge/csv/files/in/this/directory/").as[String].take(1000)

val df = spark.read
.option("header", true)
.option("sep", ",")
.option("inferSchema", true)
.csv(spark.createDataset(lines))

display(df)
```

Inferring schema for text formats is hard and it can be done this way for the csv and json (but not if it's a multi-line json) formats.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Clean straightforward way to just partially read a file in Spark

Answer (score 3):

Since PySpark 2.3 you can simply load data as text, limit, and apply csv reader on the result:

```py
(spark
  .read
  .options(inferSchema="true", header="true")
  .csv(
      spark.read.text("/path/to/file")
          .limit(20)                   # Apply limit
          .rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x)))  # Convert to RDD[str]
```

Scala counterpart is available since Spark 2.2:

```scala
spark
  .read
  .options(Map("inferSchema" -> "true", "header" -> "true"))
  .csv(spark.read.text("/path/to/file").limit(20).as[String])
```

In Spark 3.0.0 or later one can also apply limit and use `from_csv` function, but it requires a schema, so it probably won't fit your requirements.

Comment: The original question doesn't preclude knowing the schema. I think it's worthwhile adding the Spark 3.0.0 solution and mentioning that _if you know the schema_ then you should provide it and not use inferSchema. That would complete this as the correct answer.

Comment: strangely that does not shows the header. maybe limit does not preserve the order of rows since it is an RDD

Answer (score 0):

Since I didn't see that solution in the answers, the pure SQL-approach is working for me:

```
df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM csv.`/path/to/file` LIMIT 10000")
```

If there is no header the columns will be named _c0, _c1, etc. No schema required.

Answer (score 0):

May be this would be helpful who is working in java.
Applying limit will not help to reduce the time. You have to collect the n rows from the file.

```
        DataFrameReader frameReader = spark
          .read()
          .format("csv")
          .option("inferSchema", "true");
    //set framereader options, delimiters etc

    List<String> dataset = spark.read().textFile(filePath).limit(MAX_FILE_READ_SIZE).collectAsList();
    return frameReader.csv(spark.createDataset(dataset, Encoders.STRING()));
```